# Sorting numpy array with lexsort. Alternative to pandas sort_values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like the order of `b` to equal the result of `a` below.

The result of `b` is not as I expected. I thought it would be sorting by the columns in ascending order but I think I misunderstood how `lexsort` works.

My goal is to be able to sort an array the way the `df` below is sorted.
I'm using `lexsort` because I think it would be the best thing to use for an array that also contained categorical values.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = np.array([[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[2,4],[0,1],[1,0],[0,2]])

a=pd.DataFrame(x).sort_values(by=[0,1], ascending=[0,1])

b=x[np.lexsort((x[:,1],x[:,0][::-1]))]

print(a)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 2):

From the docs, it should be `last, first` to get the sort order:

```py
sorter = np.lexsort((x[:, 1], x[:, 0]))

x[sorter][::-1] # sorting in descending order
Out[899]: 
array([[2, 4],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 2],
       [2, 1],
       [1, 4],
       [1, 3],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 1]])
```

To simulate descending on one end, with ascending on the other, you could combine `np.unique`, with `np.split` and `np.concatenate`:

```py
temp = x[sorter]
_, s = np.unique(temp[:, 0], return_counts=True)
np.concatenate(np.split(temp, s.cumsum())[::-1])
Out[972]: 
array([[2, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 4],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2]])
```

Comment: My real data will have many columns and a mix of ascending 0/1 settings. Your solution works on the example but what if the order had to be ascending=[0,1]?

Comment: Any particular reason y u r not using pandas for this?

Comment: I have to do this operation millions of times and trying to cut down on the time. The pandas code takes 853 microseconds and numpy takes 2.78. I thought there has to be a simple way to not rely on pandas but it is more tricky than it looks.

Comment: you could do an `np.spit` with the return counts, but then you lose some speed; added it to the example. you could probably write a function and adjust it sort of